# CPU-GPU hardware acceleration for large node graph visualizations

Tags: cytoscape

I'm looking to visualize a large node network (well over a million nodes and edges) and am looking for the proper tool to do this. Cytoscape has many of the functionalities we're looking for, but it isn't clear if it will support this scale of network, especially for interactive use.

The most likely way for this to be feasible is to parallelize the visualization with multiple cpus or gpus. Can this be done in Cytoscape?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you have over a million nodes and their edges or a total count of over a million (nodes+edges).  If the latter, as long as you have enough memory on your machine (and a little patience) Cytoscape can handle that fine.  I've rendered graphs with well over that on my 32Gb Mac Laptop.  The initial read and render of the graph might take a bit, but once it's rendered, the manipulation of the graph is quite fast.  For really large graphs (>5,000,000 edges) I generally use a 64Gb desktop machine.  Oh, and for layouts, I recommend the Prefuse force directed layout -- it scales the best...

-- scooter